# Python - Selenium - Navigation

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, touch-event, sendkeys

Actually, I am trying to navigate without using click event or function in python as well as JavaScript. I have tried send keys - Keys. RETURN that is working for some elements and showing an error as element not interactable for some elements. I have tried Touch event in JavaScript that also not worked.

I have tried send keys in python, touch events in JavaScript.

I need to find a different way rather than click functions.

Comment: Include examples of what you tried.

Comment: sometimes the only proper eventhandler will be for onclick... one way around that is to get the href attribute and then navigate to that URL.  That won't work for all sites/links, though.  Include the DOM of a page where you are having troubles.  You may also want to explain why you are trying to avoid clicking.